# Access items in nested php array

Tags: php

I have a php array structure called `array`, which I am trying to understand.

```
1. $array['vin'][$i]['witness'][$j] = substr($data, 0, $witnesslength);;
2. $array['vin'][$i]['witness']['hex'] = $witnesshex;
```

Line 1 implies that the value of key `'witness'` is a list. Line 2 implies that the value of key `'witness'` is a nested key with name `'hex'`.

I'm trying to get my head around how it works but I can't. Not knowing much about php makes things worse.

Source: [link](https://github.com/in3rsha/bitcoin-to-neo4j/blob/master/functions/tx.php), Line 1: line 122, Line 2: line 128 in the source code.

Comment: `$array['vin'][$i]['witness']` is an array. Some of the items have been added using numeric keys ($j = 0, 1, 2, ...), and one gets added using the string key `'hex'`.

Comment: What exactly you don't understand? `$array['vin'][$i]['witness']` has keys `hex` and whatever value is in `$j`, e.g. `[0 => ..., 1 => ..., 'hex' => ...]`

Comment: @Justinas I don't know much about php. I think in python terms and what you're explaining is not very intuitive. That's why I was confused

Comment: @Andreas So learn PHP arrays

Comment: A good way to start would be the [PHP documentation for arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). It explains keys can be strings.